# Shopify Ajax API is not accepting properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, shopify

I am trying to pass three products through the shopify ajax api. It sends over the variant id and quantity but not the properties. the code is below. if I add request.properties to the Shopify.addItem function it stops after one item and gives me a pop saying that one item has been added to the cart. It does not add the other two items nor does it redirect. If I remove request.properties from the Shopify.addItem function it adds all three items to the cart but with no properties.

FINAL CODE Revised from @miglio code

```
var FreeTrial={
    data:[],
    ini:0,
    total:0,
    addItem:function(qty,id,properties,callback) {
        var params = {quantity:qty,id:id};
        if(properties != false){
            params.properties = properties;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            dataType: 'json',
            async:false,
            data: params,
            success: function(){
                if(typeof callback === 'function'){
                    callback();
                }
            },
            error: function(){}
        });
    },
    recursive:function(){
        FreeTrial.addItem(FreeTrial.data[FreeTrial.ini].qty,FreeTrial.data[FreeTrial.ini].id,FreeTrial.data[FreeTrial.ini].properties,function(){
          //console.log(FreeTrial.data[FreeTrial.ini]);
          FreeTrial.ini += 1;
          if(FreeTrial.ini < FreeTrial.total){
            FreeTrial.recursive();
          }else{
            //return false;
            document.location.href = '/cart';
          }
        });
      },

    begin:function(){
        /* SET YOUR ARRAY QTY's' ID's*/
        FreeTrial.data = [
            {
                "qty": '1',
                "id": 'VARIANT_ID_GOES_HERE',
                "properties": false
            },
            {
                "qty": '1',
                "id": 'VARIANT_ID_GOES_HERE',
                "properties": false
            },
            {
                "qty": '1',
                "id": 'VARIANT_ID_GOES_HERE',
                "properties": false
            },
            {
                "qty": '1',
                "id": 'VARIANT_ID_GOES_HERE',
                "properties": false
            },
            {
                "qty": '1',
                "id": 'VARIANT_ID_GOES_HERE',
                "properties": {
                    "recurring_price": "200.00",
                    "shipping_interval_frequency": "30",
                    "shipping_interval_unit_type": "days",
                    "subscription_id": "12599"
                  }
            }
        ];
        FreeTrial.total = FreeTrial.data.length;
        FreeTrial.recursive();
    }
  }

  FreeTrial.begin();
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: I dont get an error. if i run the code as above it only adds one item to the cart and it does not redirect to the cart. if I remove "request.properties" from addItem function it adds all three items to the cart but with out the properties

Comment: can you show the code of `Shopify.addItem()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add properties I use this function and work fine for me.

```
addItem=function(qty,id,properties,callback) {
  var params = {quantity:qty,id:id};
  if(properties != false){
      params.properties = properties;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback();
        }
    },
    error: function(){}
  });
}

//Example :
var qty = 1;
var id  = 123456;//variant_id
var properties: {
  "recurring_price": "12",
  "shipping_interval_frequency": "34",
  "shipping_interval_unit_type": "56",
  "subscription_id": "78"
}
//
addItem(qty,id,properties,function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

Well, I did this code for multiple items and a save in a gist:
   [multiple add to cart](https://gist.github.com/mig1098/0b0bf19900dce8584331)

Comment: how would I do that with three items?

Comment: a loop using the `callback`

Comment: I have added what I have to my original post under REVISED CODE. it is working however, it always gives me one less than what I actually have

Comment: I am replacing my original code with the final code for anyone out there that needs to do this. Thank you @miglio

Comment: change var properties = {

Answer (score 1):

Any POST to the endpoint url: '/cart/add.js', can include properties. If the properties are setup correctly, it works like a charm. You can assign as many properties to a variant as you want. Has been working for what, 5 years now? This function has been working for that long at least... no trouble.

```
addItemWithProperties: function(variant_id, quantity, properties, callback) {
  var quantity = quantity || 1;
  if(properties) {
    var data = properties.join("&")+"&quantity="+quantity+"&id="+variant_id;
  } else {
    var data = "quantity="+quantity+"&id="+variant_id;
  }
  var params = {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cart/add.js",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(line_item) {
      if((typeof callback) === "function") {
        callback(line_item)
      } else {
        Shopify.onItemAdded(line_item)
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.api.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus)
    }
  };
  $.ajax(params)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

edit. I guess you could do the call manually

[add to cart](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#add-to-cart)

---

Considering the Shopify.addItem() function is, [straight off their API](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api) I'm not sure you can simply add a parameter like that.

My guess is that the extra parameter has the effect that the function doesn't run.

Comment: yes, I have now found that out as well. I will revise the code above. I still can not get the properties to pass through